# django-import-export ForeignKeyWidget doesn't do lookup

Tags: python, django, excel, django-import-export

I'm trying to import an xls file with django-import-export.

This is what I have:

```
class CourseResource(resources.ModelResource):

   course_number = fields.Field(column_name='Kursnummer', attribute='course_number', widget=CharWidget())

   school_year = fields.Field(column_name='Schuljahr', attribute='school_year',
                          widget=ForeignKeyWidget(model=SchoolYear, field='name'))


   #other fields....

   class Meta:
       model = Course
       exclude = ('students')
       export_order = ('id', 'course_number', 'school_year')
```

The SchoolYear model:

```
class SchoolYear(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True)
   start_date = models.DateField(verbose_name="Beginn")
   end_date = models.DateField(verbose_name="Ende")

   def __str__(self):
       return self.name

   def __unicode__(self):
       return self.name
```

The Course model:

```
class Course(models.Model):

   course_number = models.CharField(max_length=25, verbose_name="Kursnummer")
   school_year = models.ForeignKey(SchoolYear, default=30, verbose_name="Schuljahr")

   #some other fields...

   students = models.ManyToManyField(Student, verbose_name="Schüler", null=True, blank=True, related_name="courses")

   class Meta:
       unique_together = ('course_number', 'school_year',)
       verbose_name = "Kurs"
       verbose_name_plural = "Kurse"
       managed = True

   def __str__(self):
       return "%s (%s)" % (self.course_number, self.school_year)
```

An example row in my excel file looks like this (second column is the course number, third column is the name of the school year, then some more field):

```
... 7aMa 2015/2016 ...
```

When I try to import the file in the django admin, I get this error message:

```
Row number: 1 - Column 'school_year': invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2015/2016' [...]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/amishelli/Dropbox/IMS/ims2/import_export/resources.py", line 441, in import_row
self.import_obj(instance, row, dry_run)
File "/Users/amishelli/Dropbox/IMS/ims2/import_export/resources.py",    line 300, in import_obj
self.import_field(field, obj, data)
File "/Users/amishelli/Dropbox/IMS/ims2/import_export/resources.py", line 290, in import_field
field.save(obj, data)
File "/Users/amishelli/Dropbox/IMS/ims2/import_export/fields.py", line 112, in save
setattr(obj, attrs[-1], self.clean(data))
File "/Users/amishelli/Dropbox/IMS/ims2/import_export/fields.py", line 68, in clean
 raise ValueError("Column '%s': %s" % (self.column_name, e))
 ValueError: Column 'school_year': invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2015/2016'
```

I presume the lookup of the ForeignKey for SchoolYear doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer now. My CourseAdmin was missing the resource class, so my CourseResource had no effect at all. I added this:

```
class CourseAdmin(ImportExportActionModelAdmin, ImportExportModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('course_number', 'school_year', 'school_subject', 'teacher', 'lessons_per_week', 'major')
    list_filter = ('school_year', 'school_subject', 'teacher')
    resource_class = CourseResource

admin.site.register(Course, CourseAdmin)
```

Works like a charm! :)